# Is it ok for a DC socket 5.5x2.1 to supply higher current than in the specifications?

Tags: current, dc, specifications, risk-analysis

I have recently bought a DC socket similar to the one below:
https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32681671586.html.

It is only used as a plug to connect a small circuit with a heating wire so there are no sensitive items in the circuit. The maximal current that should flow would be 2A supplied by an adjustable voltage supply unit allowing max 24V and 3A. (At 24V, the maximal supplied voltage, the current flowing though the heating unit should be 2A and achieve maximum temperature).

Later I found out that the connector above is supposed to be used up to max. 1A and 24V. Am I running the risk of current melting the plastics there with 2A or something else I should worry about?

I currently use something like this: https://jetztfunkts.de/en/dc-anschlussleitung-dc-buchse-2-1-x-5-5-mm-auf-freies-ende-zwillingslitze-25-cm and it works fine but it can't be installed on the board.

Comment: Probably not. It will run hot.

Comment: So is the main issue for allowing higher currents that such components can't handle the heat that is generated by their internal resistance?

Comment: If your "circuit with a heating wire" is close to the connector you might need to look for [glow wire compatible](https://www.amphenol-icc.com/connect/learn-about-glow-wire-compatibility.html) connectors, in addition to suitable current ratings.

Comment: _"Later I found out that the connector above is supposed to be used up until max. 1A and 24V."_ - where did get this information?

Comment: I asked the seller as it was not specified in the listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not ok. Not a good idea.

The current rating of a Switch is typically a function of the contact resistance and materials of construction.

Heating power is a function of current squared
Power = I^2 * R
And contact resistance is often temperature dependent. Max temp may deal with softening of the plastic (which can cause even higher contact resistance and power loss after many cycles or even one prolonged cycle).  Contact resistance can also increase if the metal used to make the switch gets hot and oxidizes in air.

Good quality parts are generally made of flame resistant plastics but, buying on AliExpress can be questionable as random datasheets or brand names are commonly assigned to parts made by small companies with no real testing behind the part's development.

Buying from Digikey, RS, Allied, Newark, Mouser or any of the known parts distributors is a much better idea if you have safety or performance concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate a bit more? I am having an issue finding a suitable component that can be installed.

Comment: Detailed added above.

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed answer. I found a part that is almost what I want. It says it supports 12V and up to 5A, and I need  24V and 2~3A. And another thing is that it is 5,7x2,1 female instead of 5,5x2,1. Do you reckon it would work and fit: https://www.conrad.de/de/p/tru-components-niedervolt-steckverbinder-buchse-einbau-vertikal-5-7-mm-2-1-mm-1-st-1582355.html. Thanks

Comment: This form is import as I want it to have M8x1 threading on the neck so that I can just screw it directly in the design and remove if needed. The exact thing is hard to find.